# Azure DevOps force core.hooksPath after clone a repository

Tags: azure-devops

I try to implement *client side git hooks* to a azure devops git repository.

I added a `.githooks` directory to the root and implement a `pre-commit` hook. I commit and push everything to the repository.

But of curse the hook is only active if I execute

`git config core.hooksPath .githooks`

after cloning the repository.

**The question is here:** is there a possiblity to set the `git config core.hooksPath` per *default* to `.githooks` otherwise it will be impossible to force a user to use a hook. :/

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I doubt there's anything built-in. +1, interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is here: is there a possiblity to set the git config
>   core.hooksPath per default to .githooks otherwise it will be
>   impossible to force a user to use a hook. :/

Sorry but I'm afraid it's **impossible** for now, as I know `Azure Devops` doesn't support such behavior. I totally understand your needs but what you want is not available in either `Azure Devops Git Repos` or `Github Repos`.

Currently you have to make your members run the `git config core.hooksPath .githooks` command manually to enable your custom hooks. We **can't avoid a manual step** here cause git hooks is designed to trigger actions at certain points **per user** instead of **per team**.

Comment: thanks for that answer. I understand the current situation and hope for an feature update in future.

Comment: It could be a good idea! And you can trying sharing your feedback by feature request in our [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).